# Two UIViewControllers on one screen without SplitViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How can I bring two uiviewcontrollers onto one screen with out using splitviewcontroller in story board ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible in the story board. You have to do that programmatically using `addChildViewController:` ([UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Scroll down to "Implementing a Container View Controller"). Container View Controller is a feature introduced in iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way that I could think about doing this is adding two Container Views in one View Controller and then giving each container view a class. You can find the container views in your objects library under "Container View"

Comment: This is the way to do it, but you don't give the container views a class. You drag out view controllers, one for each container view, and then connect them to the container views with an embed segue. The view controllers will automatically resize to the size of the container view when you connect them.